# Integrating a ClickOnce app with Outlook

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, outlook, integration

I have a ClickOnce app that used to be run by users with Power User privileges.  So to integrate to outlook (e.g. syncing of emails, appointments and addresses) I used a 3rd party component from Add-In Express, which includes an ActiveX DLL.

So when the user would download my app, I'd register the ActiveX DLL (if it wasn't already registered) and then would just interop with it in the application.

Well, now the users had their privileges changed to standard limited User.  Which means that they can't register DLLs (since it writes to the registry keys that are off limit).  And the integration with Outlook fails, of course.

What are some of options to integrate with Outlook for my situation?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is really no way round it as the "standard" user as they can not register DLLs. You can package VSTO into a msi and install it for all users on the machine but the user that installed it would have to have the right rights to do that probally local admin.
Its probaly best to find out how they Install msi apps ? and use that user.